# Mean square integrable

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f:$ $X  \rightarrow R$ be a measurable function such that f is mean square integrable.

(i.e $ \int f^2 dm< \infty$).
Show that if $ m(X)< \infty$ then f is integrable

I tried to show that : $\{x \in X ; f(x)= \infty \}$ has measure zero but that did not take me anywhere, then i decided to find g integrable such that :$g>|f|$ and there i was stuck. I appreciate your suggestions  and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E=\{x\in X : |f(x)|\geq 1\}$
and $E^{c}=\{x\in X :|f(x)|<1\}$

$\int_X f \ d m =\int_E f \ d m +\int_{E^c} f \ d m$

observe that when $ x \in E$:  $|f(x)|\leq f^2(x)$ implies: 
$\int_E |f| \ d m$ $\leq \int_E f^2 \ d m < \infty$

on the other hand:
observe that when $x\in E^{c}$:  $|f(X)|<1$:
$\int_{E^c} |f| \ d m < \int_{E^c} 1\ d m= m(E^c) \leq m(X)< \infty$

consequently f is lebesgue integrable as$ \int_X |f| \ d m< \infty$.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much.